# Self-study. Exercise on uniform distribution over a unit square

Tags: probability, self-study, joint-distribution, uniform-distribution

Given following problem:

[image]

Here is my approach: $P(Z<z) = P(log(X) + log(Y) < z)= P(XY<e^z)$ And here I use frequntiest approach where rv belongs to some set A, namely $P(X \in A) =\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$. Because $XY$ is an area of some rectangle shape which lies within unit  square. So, $P(XY<e^z) = \frac{e^z}{1}=e^z$

But it seems to be completely wrong. Actual solution is a little bit more complicated( I can provide if needed...)

What is wrong with my approach, where I'm mistaken?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that $XY$ is not uniformly distributed -- it has some distribution between 0 and 1, but your $P(XY\lt e^z)=e^z$ is only valid if $XY$ has a uniform distribution

Comment: Use the convolution formula after deriving the density of a log-Uniform from its cdf.

Comment: @ThomasLumley: Thank you for reply!   $XY$ is not uniform, because we don't know for sure that it is a square hence uniform, right?

Comment: That's one way to think about  it. Another way is that $XY$ is  small  if either $X$ is small or $Y$ is small, so $XY$ is more likely to be small than large

Comment: @ThomasLumley: Thank you again for your time! Your statement above is just another argument(or heuristics
) that $XY$ is not uniform, correct?

Comment: Yes. There are other problems, too. The answer does not have a closed-form CDF,  only pdf, so trying to get the CDF directly  won't work.  You really do  need the approach in comment 2:  work out the distribution  of  $\log X$ and then  work out or look up  the   distribution of the  sum of two of them.